# how to set VScode "mypy-type-checker.args" argument for python

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, python-telegram-bot

I am learning python , i use Vs code as my IDE, i am have some very strange and annoying errors.

## **examples**:

when i import modules
`import telegram`
i get error
`"telegram" is not accessed Pylance invalid syntaxMypysyntax (module) telegram`
on my files, which is very annoying. I have write `import telegram #type:ignore` for the error to go away.

when i also write

```
    async def hello(self, update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
        await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Hello, my name is MAS.")
```

i get this error on `chat_id=update.effective_chat.id`

```
 Item "None" of "Optional[Chat]" has no attribute "id"Mypyunion-attr
 Item "None" of "Optional[Chat]" has no attribute "id"Mypyunion-attr
 Item "None" of "Optional[Chat]" has no attribute "id"Mypyunion-attr
 Item "None" of "Optional[Chat]" has no attribute "id"Mypyunion-attr
 Item "None" of "Optional[Chat]" has no attribute "id"Mypyunion-attr
 (property) effective_chat: Chat | None
```

.

Even with these errors i runs the files perfectly without any issues, i don't why vscode is acting up. it is impacting my productivity. i have to add `#type:ignore` to make these errors go away.

i have these running extensions.

> [image: image of running extensions]

I have searched all of google and stack overflow and found nothing that solve my problem. i came across `mypy-type-checker.args` on [Vscode marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.mypy-type-checker#settings:%7E:text=Description-,mypy%2Dtype%2Dchecker.args,-%5B%5D).
i believe it could solve my problem, but there is no docs on how to set the arguments. nothing at all on vscode marketplace.
The [docs for mypy](https://www.mypy-lang.org/) even made less sense to me as a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I enabled Copilot, ask it to explain the probem to me . it told me to do

```
  if update.effective_chat is not None:
        await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Hello, my name is MAS, i am your bot that provides movies to you for free.")
```

instead of

```
         await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Hello, my name is MAS, i am your bot that provides movies to you for free.")
```

My code is now error free.
if you have a Copilot subscription enable the extension to *6 your productivity.

Comment: Hi daviddanielng, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as the answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 1):

> "telegram" is not accessed Pylance invalid syntaxMypysyntax (module) telegram

I *suspect* that this can have something to do with the PyPi project being named `python-telegram-bot` and not `telegram`. I know that other IDEs also keep looking for a project named `telegram` and can't find it. Since I'm not working with VSCode, this only a guessr though.

> Item "None" of "Optional[Chat]" has no attribute "id"Mypyunion-attr

This is currently a known limitation in PTBs type hinting. Basically it's extremely hard to specify the type hinting of attributes that are there only for *specific* updates depend on which handler the callback function is being used in. See also [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/issues/3332) for discussion.

Explicit run-time checks are one option, using [`typing.cast`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/typing.html?highlight=cast#typing.cast) can be another.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Comment: hi, thanks for the replay. i got the first error because my laptop is taking too long to scan my files and installed modules. i had way too many running extension, like Emmet, tailwind intellisense, many jQuery and bootstrap snippets extension and much more. i move form front-end to back-end programming. uninstalling unused extension freed resources on my computer in turn removed the first error. i was able to remove the second error with  [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77691661/19310480)

Answer (score -1):

You can open your settings and search for `python.analysis.typeCheckingMode` then choose **off** which is the default choice.

[image]

Comment: [picture of `python.analysis.typeCheckingMode` off](https://i.imgur.com/eRk455c.png) it is turned off.